# Increment field value in a CKRecord variable without fetching?

Tags: ios, cloudkit

I am curious is it somehow possible to increment a field value in a CKRecord variable without fetching? So on client I am not curious about the recent value, I just want to increase whatever be the value is. The reason,  operation should be as quick and easy as possible, instead of two message 'stream', I want initiate only one.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Unfortunately you can not. You have to read, change and then write the record. Make sure that you use the [CKModifyRecordsOperation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/CloudKit/Reference/CKModifyRecordsOperation_class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/cl/CKModifyRecordsOperation) and leave the savePolicy to  `CKRecordSaveIfServerRecordUnchanged` If you get an error then you could try read and write the record again.

Comment: As a slight improvement, you don't need to fetch the record again if you get a `CKErrorServerRecordChanged` error- the server's copy of the record will be in the error's `userInfo` dictionary under the key `CKRecordChangedErrorServerRecordKey`. You can merge your changes into that record and attempt another save using that record.