# "Atomic increment" with CloudKit

Tags: ios, swift, cloudkit

I want to implement a counter using CloudKit. Let's say I have a field called `count` of type `Int(64)`. How can I go about implementing this counter so that multiple users can increment it at the same time?

If multiple users increment this counter at the same time, my `CKModifyRecordsOperation` might fail because of the conflict. I could take this failure and recursively try to save my record, but this doesn't work at scale.

In 2011, Parse launched a simple solution called atomic increment. You could write code like this and not worry about multiple users creating conflicting values: `[gameScore incrementKey:@"score" byAmount:[NSNumber numberWithInt:10]`. (That post [here](http://blog.parse.com/learn/engineering/increment-operators/))

How can I do this with CloudKit?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't believe CloudKit has similar atomic increment functionality built in. But a similar effect can be achieved by setting `savePolicy` on the `CKModifyRecordsOperation` to `ifServerRecordUnchanged` and checking for a `serverRecordChanged` error ([docs](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/cloudkit/ckerror.code/1515035-serverrecordchanged)).

There is an existing answer here to a slightly different question: [Increment field value in a CKRecord variable without fetching?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29373056/increment-field-value-in-a-ckrecord-variable-without-fetching)

Comment: I was hoping that there would be a more elegant backend solution for this, but this does help make the resave process as efficient as possible. Thank you.